# luci-app-sqm "404 Not Found" after sysupgrade to 18.06.1

Tags: openwrt

I upgraded to Openwrt 18.06.1, from lede-17.01.4, using "sysupgrade".  Now I can't open the SQM page in the LUCI web interface.  Why?

I backed up and restored my openwrt config, using the web interface, and installed `luci-app-sqm` again.

By contrast, the UPNP page (from the extra package `luci-app-upnp`) seems to be displaying without any problem.

My first problem was that the SQM page in the web interface (`https://openwrt/cgi-bin/luci/admin/network/sqm`) shows

> 404 Not Found
>
> Sorry, the object you requested was not found.
>   Unable to dispatch: /cgi-bin/luci/admin/network/sqm

Also, I have tried removing the LUCI cache (`rm -r /tmp/luci-indexcache /tmp/luci-modulecache`).  I think this has usually been necessary to get new menu items to show up.  This time it disappeared the SQM item from the menu :(.

I have also tried `rm /etc/config/sqm`, then removing and re-installing `sqm`.  This doesn't help anything, but it shows some errors.  Perhaps they are relevant.

```
# opkg remove luci-app-sqm sqm
Removing package luci-app-sqm from root...
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
uci: Entry not found

# opkg install luci-app-sqm
Installing luci-app-sqm (1.2.3-1) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/packages/mips_24kc/packages/luci-app-sqm_1.2.3-1_all.ipk
Configuring luci-app-sqm.
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
uci: Entry not found
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
uci: Entry not found
```

I cannot find any relevant or unexpected errors in `logread`.

---

My hardware is Netgear WNDR3800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were still stale state in SQM files.  Notice that your remove command did not remove a `sqm` package.

The correct name is `sqm-scripts`.  Then the problem was fixed, after the following:

```
# opkg remove luci-app-sqm sqm-scripts
Removing package luci-app-sqm from root...
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
uci: Entry not found
Removing package sqm-scripts from root...
/usr/lib/sqm/run.sh: .: line 12: can't open '/etc/sqm/sqm.conf': No such file or directory
Not deleting modified conffile /etc/sqm/sqm.conf.
Not deleting modified conffile /etc/config/sqm.
Collected errors:
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/sqm/sqm.conf: No such file or directory.
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/config/sqm: No such file or directory.

# opkg install luci-app-sqm
Installing luci-app-sqm (1.2.3-1) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/packages/mips_24kc/packages/luci-app-sqm_1.2.3-1_all.ipk
Installing sqm-scripts (1.2.3-1) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.1/packages/mips_24kc/packages/sqm-scripts_1.2.3-1_all.ipk
Configuring sqm-scripts.
Configuring luci-app-sqm.
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
```

I think the stale state was `/etc/sqm/sqm.conf`.

---

You can check the system for package config files which differ from the defaults like this:

```
# opkg list-changed-conffiles
/etc/group
/etc/hosts
/etc/passwd
/etc/profile
/etc/services
/etc/shadow
/etc/sysctl.conf
/etc/config/ddns
/etc/config/dhcp
/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
/etc/config/firewall
/etc/config/luci
/etc/config/ucitrack
/etc/config/upnpd
/etc/opkg/customfeeds.conf
/etc/config/snmpd
/etc/config/sqm
/etc/sqm/sqm.conf
/etc/config/uhttpd
Collected errors:
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/config/sqm: No such file or directory.
 * file_sha256sum_alloc: Failed to open file /etc/sqm/sqm.conf: No such file or directory.
```

Some of these names might be considered alarming.  ala "It is possible that some main settings in users/groups, network, switch etc. config has changed so that the old settings from 15.05 (or 17.01) will not be ok in 17.01 or 18.06 or later versions. After major version upgrades it may be better to create the critical config files from scratch by hand, starting from the new default config so that the current defaults form the starting base."